# How can I get Windows Media Center on my Windows 8 Enterprise install?

Tags: windows-8, windows-media-center

Windows Media Center is no longer part of the default install for any Windows SKU, due to its low use.  I do use it, and plan on installing it.

For a limited time, the WMC install is free, so I wanted to get in on that.  I went [to the website](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/feature-packs) where you can get a free product key, and signed up.

*However,* the installation instructions on the page tell me to use **Add Features to Windows 8** to install the upgrade.

[image]
<sup>[image ganked from WinSuperSite](http://www.winsupersite.com/article/windows8/windows-8-secrets-add-features-windows-8-143151)</sup>

**Here's the problem:**  This option doesn't appear to be available on Windows 8 Enterprise installs.

I've searched for it by name, and tried to use the old-school ["Turn Windows Features On and Off"](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Turn-Windows-features-on-or-off) method of adding features.  No luck.

**So, how can one install the WMC upgrade on a box with Windows 8 Enterprise?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Media Center is not available to Windows 8 Enterprise, it's for Professional edition only.

Source: [Windows 8 Enterprise - Microsoft.com](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enterprise/products-and-technologies/windows-8/enterprise-edition.aspx)

> Windows 8 Enterprise is not eligible for the aftermarket Pro Pack add-on which includes DVD playback.

Comment: Sadly, @Indrek is totally correct.  Unlike Windows 7, where Enterprise included everything in Home Premium, including Media Center, in Windows 8, it's not possible.

Comment: @PJC: Role reversal.  Not a big deal for me (MSDN account), but a bigger one for people trying to figure out which sku to buy.

Comment: @Will - All the information is posted on Microsoft's account, with a nice comparision table, helpful to look at the information before choosing a sku.

Comment: @will here you go http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8_editions

Answer (score 1):

I found this straight from Microsoft when describing the details of the promo for Windows Media Center. (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/terms-conditions-feature-packs)

**Will businesses or enterprise be eligible for this promotion?**

The promotion is for individual customers like students, home users, and enthusiasts. *Organizations can be eligible subject to this maximum limit per organization.*

Microsoft states right there that enterprise customers are eligible but they are still subject to the limit of 5 per customer. So, wtf. I'm calling Microsoft..

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to say with this. The question was about which Windows 8 *editions* are eligible for the Pro Pack, not which *customers*. Business customers and organisations are eligible if they're running Windows 8 or Windows 8 Pro.

Comment: The point is that it matters if it is a Volume License version (like Enterprise or Pro VL) because for some reason MS has taken away the ability to add features for all Volume License editions...even though as Kain says, it is listed as if it is supported.