# What's the "ultimate" version of Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

I am asking this question because I always like to download the full package with all the advantages of Windows.

For example Windows XP Professional or Windows 7 Ultimate, but as we all know that Microsoft released several versions for Windows 8 and as far as I know the Enterprise version is the full package (Windows 8 equivalent of Windows 7 Ultimate).

But when I tried to download Windows 8 Enterprise edition I noticed that its size is less compared to some other versions. Here's some screenshots from MSDN download site:

[image]

[image]

[image]

As is evident the Enterprise version is less in size compared to the standard version. Why is that the case?

And which version do I need to download to get the *full* experience.

Comment: Don't know about the sizes, but do note that [Windows 8 Enterprise cannot use the Media Center pack](http://superuser.com/q/493493/108226), that's for Pro only.

Comment: Makes sense. At least at work I haven't seen anyone watching DVDs.

Comment: thanks for reply i don't care about media center and i watched size to comparison which have full package

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Enterprise edition has a few smaller features that Windows 8 Pro doesn't, including Windows To Go, which lets you create a portable version of Windows and run it off a USB flash drive. However, as Indrek said above, Enterprise isn't able to get Media Center. In other words, there is no "complete" edition of Windows 8 that has all of the possible features.

If you consider Media Center important, then use Windows 8 Pro. Otherwise, I would consider Windows 8 Enterprise to be the most "complete" package.

Comment: thanks for help and i think for me professional version is very recommend to me like i said to AbhishekGirish

Answer (score 1):

You should first figure out your requirements. Previously with Windows Vista and even Windows 7 (if I've not mistaken), Microsoft put some really good consumer features into the Premium & Ultimate versions only. But its not the case with Windows 8. If you are looking at experiencing all the consumer features of Windows 8, you can simply stick with Windows 8.

If you are a developer or looking for some advanced features such as Hyper-V, Encrypting File System, Remote Desktop server, etc.. you should go with Windows 8 Pro.

I personally feel you can leave out Windows 8 Enterprise. It is targetted towards IT organizations.

You can find more details [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8_editions#Comparison_chart) and [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/compare)

Comment: thanks man and i agree with you because i see alot of user advise us to download pro version for home user so i will do that thanks for help